# Is it possible to detect when the user answers the Bluetooth permission request on iOS?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, key-value-observing

Most of the permission requests on iOS these days have an API with a callback for when the user answers the request alert. Is it possible to get a similar effect for the Bluetooth permission request? It would be nice to be able to have our app respond to the user answering the alert.

I've tried using KVO, but my observer method doesn't get called:

```
private static var obsContext = 0

...

if CBCentralManager.authorization == .notDetermined {
  CBCentralManager.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "authorization", context: &MyClass.obsContext)
}

...

@objc override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?,
                                 change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?,
                                 context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
  if context == &MyClass.obsContext {
    ...
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there another way to do this? Or is it just not possible for Bluetooth?

Comment: You won't get a `.poweredOn` state transition until the user approves access. You can set a flag if permission isn't granted and then use that when you transition to `.poweredOn`. This doesn't help if they deny the request. The other thing you can do is observe the `didBecomeActive` state when requesting permission. Your app will become inactive when the prompt is shown and become active again once the user has responded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paulw11's suggestion worked for me. If I watch for the `UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification` notification, I can detect when the permission request dialog is dismissed. For safety, I'm also watching for `UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification` in case the user puts the device to sleep or otherwise exits the app without responding to the dialog.